# How to play sound on button click, even if MediaPlayer is already playing a sound?

Tags: android, button, audio, android-mediaplayer

On button click, I wrote some code to play a simple sound. I would like this sound to play even over previously created sound with the same button (example, if the user clicks the button repeatedly and quickly.

Right now, the code does not play any sound until the previously created sound is completely finished.

I tried doing player.pause() and then player.seekTo(0) on button click, but then the previously created sound gets cut off. This is not what I want. I would like all sounds to finish in their entirety. If the first sound is still playing, I want sound 2 (second quick button press) to play on top (same for sound 3, 4, (user can probably click 5-6 times before the first sound finishes.) Should I make 6 mediaPlayer objects and onclick check if 1st is playing, if so play 2, if 2 is playing, play 3, etc....? There must be a more efficient way.

This code does not play sound until the previous sound is completely finished:

```
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player1.start();
            return;
        }
    });
```

This code cuts off previously created sound:

```
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    player1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player1.pause();
            player1.seekTo(0);
            player1.start();
            return;
        }
    });
```

How can I play sound on each click, and overlap previously created sound? (if user clicks the button quickly enough to where this is necessary)?

Comment: Thought of something: Should I go through the process of creating new MediaPlayer objects on each click and then destroying them after they play their sounds? Is this safe to do/memory efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new player for each time you want to play a sound, try this. I didn't tested it.

```
button = findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick1);
        player.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: But if the user clicks 100 times, I'll have created 100 MediaPlayer objects... won't the app run slow/crash?

Comment: how much do you max want to create?
the garbage collector delete all objects without a reference, so there will be deleted after some time.

Comment: The user can click indefinitively. It would be ideal if I can just use 1 MediaPlayer object.

Comment: then this could be the answer, maybee you could have an array of max 10 or 20 media player and increment over it

EDIT: think of your object like a real cd player, if you press play, the sound plays, after you press play multible times, nothing will happen, so you need an other player to play the sound simultaneously

Comment: I think incrementing over 10 mediaplayers might be the solution. I'm trying to write the code right now and I'll let you know how it works

Answer (score 0):

Dinesh's answer is almost there, only that you need to keep the created MediaPlayer.

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;

    if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPalying()) {
      mPlayer.stop();
      ...
    }
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, raw);
    ...
```

Because a different MediaPlayer is created if you play a different raw.

Comment: I would like the same raw played each time the button is click, and I would like the sounds to overlap (if button is pressed repeatedly). won't your code cut the previously created sound off?